# How do I return a json response using scala lift?

Tags: scala, lift

How do I return a list as a json response?

So say querying /list?id=123 returns

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `net.liftweb.json` package has what you are looking for. The following snippet should help you get a JSON object that can be returned and converted into a response:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val list = //create list
Extraction.decompose(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return in in your `RestHelper`, like this:

```
    case Get("test" :: Nil, req) =>
        JArray(List(JString("1"), JString("2"))): LiftResponse
```

Normally, of course, you don't inline the JSON but take it out of a database, or create it with some DSL. (Examples: https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json )